Is there a way to compute this table in Python?
I'm having trouble computing this table in python since the x-axis and y-axis have ranges. Is there a way I can input this table without manually putting in all numbers within the ranges? For example, how the y-axis has a row 7-49; I wish to have one row for that.
I tried using a list/dictionary but realized I could not use ranges for those. Also, I tried dataframe but am not sure how to approach that, possibly pandas. I'm using this table to determine the dividing factor for this equation: TC minus HDL-C minus TG/adjustable factor. The adjustable factor would come from the table based on the TG and HDLC values.
For example, if someone has TC = 332, HDL-C = 55.9, TG = 206 (As the inputs); their factor would be 5.3 and the equation would be 332 - 55.9 - 206/5.3 = 237.2. That is what I'm trying to program.
Martian-Hopkins Look-up Table
TG,mg/dL    HDL-C <100  100-129 130-159 160-189 190-219 >=220
7-49        0   3.5 3.4 3.3 3.3 3.2 3.1
50-56       50  4.0 3.9 3.7 3.6 3.6 3.4
57-61       57  4.3 4.1 4.0 3.9 3.8 3.6
62-66       62  4.5 4.3 4.1 4.0 3.9 3.9
67-71       67  4.7 4.4 4.3 4.2 4.1 3.9
72-75       72  4.8 4.6 4.4 4.2 4.2 4.1
76-79       76  4.9 4.6 4.5 4.3 4.3 4.2
80-83       80  5.0 4.8 4.6 4.4 4.3 4.2
84-87       84  5.1 4.8 4.6 4.5 4.4 4.3
88-92       88  5.2 4.9 4.7 4.6 4.4 4.3
93-96       93  5.3 5.0 4.8 4.7 4.5 4.4
97-100    97    5.4 5.1 4.8 4.7 4.5 4.3
101-105   101   5.5 5.2 5.0 4.7 4.6 4.5
106-110   106   5.6 5.3 5.0 4.8 4.6 4.5
111-115   111   5.7 5.4 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.5
116-120   116   5.8 5.5 5.2 5.0 4.8 4.6
121-126   121   6.0 5.5 5.3 5.0 4.8 4.6
127-132   127   6.1 5.7 5.3 5.1 4.9 4.7
133-138   133   6.2 5.8 5.4 5.2 5.0 4.7
139-146   139   6.3 5.9 5.6 5.3 5.0 4.8
147-154   147   6.5 6.0 5.7 5.4 5.1 4.8
155-163   155   6.7 6.2 5.8 5.4 5.2 4.9
164-173   164   6.8 6.3 5.9 5.5 5.3 5.0
174-185   174   7.0 6.5 6.0 5.7 5.4 5.1
186-201   186   7.3 6.7 6.2 5.8 5.5 5.2
202-220   202   7.6 6.9 6.4 6.0 5.6 5.3
221-247   221   8.0 7.2 6.6 6.2 5.9 5.4
248-292   248   8.5 7.6 7.0 6.5 6.1 5.6
293-399   293   9.5 8.3 7.5 7.0 6.5 5.9
400-409     400 10.4    8.7 7.9 7.3 6.7 6.1
410-419     410 10.7    8.9 7.9 7.3 6.7 6.0
420-429     420 10.3    8.9 7.9 7.4 6.8 6.0
430-439     430 11.2    8.9 8.0 7.3 6.8 6.0
440-449     440 12.0    9.0 8.0 7.5 6.9 6.0
450-459     450 11.3    9.3 8.2 7.4 7.0 6.0
460-469     460 12.3    9.2 8.3 7.7 6.9 6.1
470-479     470 10.6    9.3 8.3 7.6 7.0 6.0
480-489     480 11.7    9.3 8.4 7.6 7.1 6.1
490-499     490 11.6    9.6 8.4 7.6 7.2 6.2
500-509     500 12.1    9.2 8.4 7.5 7.1 6.2
510-519     510 12.3    9.9 8.5 7.9 7.1 6.3
520-529     520 12.0    9.8 8.7 7.7 7.1 6.3
530-539     530 12.0    9.8 8.7 7.8 7.2 6.3
540-549     540 11.3    10.0    8.8 7.8 7.4 6.3
550-559     550 12.2    10.2    8.8 8.0 7.4 6.2
560-569     560 13.8    10.2    8.7 8.1 7.2 6.2
570-579     570 15.4    10.4    8.9 8.0 7.3 6.2
580-589     580 12.7    10.5    9.1 8.3 7.3 6.4
590-599     590 12.5    10.5    9.2 8.3 7.2 5.9
600-609     600 13.7    10.5    8.9 8.2 7.6 6.3
610-619     610 15.4    10.5    9.1 8.4 7.5 6.4
620-629     620 16.4    11.3    9.2 8.5 7.5 6.4
630-639     630 14.1    11.6    9.4 8.2 7.3 6.2
640-649     640 14.8    11.0    9.1 8.1 7.5 6.6
650-659     650 14.2    11.0    9.2 8.3 7.5 6.4
660-669     660 15.0    10.9    9.2 8.3 7.5 6.5
670-679     670 14.2    11.0    9.3 8.6 7.6 6.7
680-689     680 16.7    11.5    9.8 8.3 7.4 6.7
690-699     690 15.0    11.6    9.8 8.4 7.8 6.5
700-709     700 16.6    11.5    9.5 8.5 7.8 6.9
710-719     710 14.5    10.9    9.7 8.5 7.8 6.4
720-729     720 16.5    11.7    9.5 8.5 7.6 6.6
730-739     730 18.2    12.2    9.9 8.9 8.2 6.6
740-749     740 17.5    11.7    9.9 8.5 7.9 6.6
750-759     750 17.5    12.9    10.2    8.8 8.1 6.4
760-769     760 19.2    11.4    9.9 8.7 8.3 6.5
770-779     770 17.3    13.4    10.4    8.6 8.2 6.7
780-789     780 23.9    12.3    10.4    9.1 7.9 6.7
790-799     790 15.6    13.0    10.7    8.7 8.0 6.7


Do you want to have individual columns for each integer in the range?

Does this answer your question? How to repeat a pandas data frame column x amount of times?

There are a couple of ways to do this.  But I think loading the data into your own custom class is a good fit for this type of problem.
You can reformat you data by converting it to JSON format that can be read by the class.  In this example each row has the keys: "TG_low", "TG_high", and "nonHDL-C".  The data is included below.
class MartinHopkinsLookup:
    def __init__(self, json_path: str):
        with open(json_path) as fp:
            self.data = json.load(fp)

    def lookup_factor(self, tc: int, tg: int) -> float:
        for row in self.data:
            if row['TG_low'] <= tg <= row['TG_high']:
                break
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'No matching range found for tg={tg}')
        for nhdl in row['nonHDL-C']:
            if nhdl['low'] <= tc <= nhdl['high']:
                return nhdl['factor']
        raise ValueError(f'No matching range found for tc={tc}')

    def __call__(self, tc: int, hdl_c: float, tg: int) -> float:
        factor = self.lookup_factor(tc, tg)
        return round(tc - hdl_c - tg / factor, 2)

Using the class looks like:
>>> mhl = MartinHopkinsLookup('path/to/table.json')
>>> mhl(332, 55.9, 206)
237.23

Here is the JSON-formatted data to be saved in a file.

[{"TG_low": 7, "TG_high": 49, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 3.5}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 3.4}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 3.3}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 3.3}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 3.2}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 3.1}]},
 {"TG_low": 50, "TG_high": 56, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 4.0}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 3.9}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 3.7}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 3.6}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 3.6}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 3.4}]},
 {"TG_low": 57, "TG_high": 61, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 4.3}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 4.1}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 4.0}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 3.9}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 3.8}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 3.6}]},
 {"TG_low": 62, "TG_high": 66, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 4.5}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 4.3}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 4.1}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 4.0}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 3.9}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 3.9}]},
 {"TG_low": 67, "TG_high": 71, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 4.7}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 4.4}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 4.3}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 4.2}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 4.1}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 3.9}]},
 {"TG_low": 72, "TG_high": 75, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 4.8}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 4.6}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 4.4}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 4.2}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 4.2}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.1}]},
 {"TG_low": 76, "TG_high": 79, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 4.9}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 4.6}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 4.5}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 4.3}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 4.3}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.2}]},
 {"TG_low": 80, "TG_high": 83, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 5.0}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 4.8}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 4.6}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 4.4}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 4.3}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.2}]},
 {"TG_low": 84, "TG_high": 87, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 5.1}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 4.8}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 4.6}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 4.5}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 4.4}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.3}]},
 {"TG_low": 88, "TG_high": 92, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 5.2}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 4.9}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 4.7}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 4.6}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 4.4}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.3}]},
 {"TG_low": 93, "TG_high": 96, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 5.3}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 5.0}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 4.8}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 4.7}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 4.5}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.4}]},
 {"TG_low": 97, "TG_high": 100, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 5.4}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 5.1}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 4.8}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 4.7}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 4.5}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.3}]},
 {"TG_low": 101, "TG_high": 105, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 5.5}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 5.2}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 5.0}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 4.7}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 4.6}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.5}]},
 {"TG_low": 106, "TG_high": 110, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 5.6}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 5.3}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 5.0}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 4.8}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 4.6}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.5}]},
 {"TG_low": 111, "TG_high": 115, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 5.7}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 5.4}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 5.1}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 4.9}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 4.7}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.5}]},
 {"TG_low": 116, "TG_high": 120, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 5.8}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 5.5}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 5.2}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 5.0}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 4.8}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.6}]},
 {"TG_low": 121, "TG_high": 126, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 6.0}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 5.5}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 5.3}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 5.0}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 4.8}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.6}]},
 {"TG_low": 127, "TG_high": 132, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 6.1}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 5.7}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 5.3}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 5.1}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 4.9}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.7}]},
 {"TG_low": 133, "TG_high": 138, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 6.2}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 5.8}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 5.4}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 5.2}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 5.0}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.7}]},
 {"TG_low": 139, "TG_high": 146, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 6.3}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 5.9}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 5.6}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 5.3}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 5.0}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.8}]},
 {"TG_low": 147, "TG_high": 154, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 6.5}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 6.0}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 5.7}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 5.4}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 5.1}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.8}]},
 {"TG_low": 155, "TG_high": 163, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 6.7}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 6.2}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 5.8}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 5.4}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 5.2}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 4.9}]},
 {"TG_low": 164, "TG_high": 173, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 6.8}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 6.3}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 5.9}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 5.5}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 5.3}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 5.0}]},
 {"TG_low": 174, "TG_high": 185, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 7.0}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 6.5}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 6.0}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 5.7}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 5.4}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 5.1}]},
 {"TG_low": 186, "TG_high": 201, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 7.3}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 6.7}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 6.2}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 5.8}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 5.5}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 5.2}]},
 {"TG_low": 202, "TG_high": 220, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 7.6}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 6.9}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 6.4}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 6.0}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 5.6}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 5.3}]},
 {"TG_low": 221, "TG_high": 247, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 8.0}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 7.2}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 6.6}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 6.2}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 5.9}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 5.4}]},
 {"TG_low": 248, "TG_high": 292, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 8.5}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 7.6}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 7.0}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 6.5}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 6.1}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 5.6}]},
 {"TG_low": 293, "TG_high": 399, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 9.5}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 8.3}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 7.5}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 7.0}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 6.5}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 5.9}]},
 {"TG_low": 400, "TG_high": 409, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 10.4}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 8.7}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 7.9}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 7.3}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 6.7}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.1}]},
 {"TG_low": 410, "TG_high": 419, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 10.7}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 8.9}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 7.9}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 7.3}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 6.7}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.0}]},
 {"TG_low": 420, "TG_high": 429, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 10.3}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 8.9}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 7.9}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 7.4}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 6.8}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.0}]},
 {"TG_low": 430, "TG_high": 439, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 11.2}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 8.9}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 8.0}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 7.3}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 6.8}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.0}]},
 {"TG_low": 440, "TG_high": 449, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 12.0}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 9.0}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 8.0}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 7.5}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 6.9}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.0}]},
 {"TG_low": 450, "TG_high": 459, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 11.3}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 9.3}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 8.2}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 7.4}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.0}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.0}]},
 {"TG_low": 460, "TG_high": 469, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 12.3}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 9.2}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 8.3}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 7.7}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 6.9}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.1}]},
 {"TG_low": 470, "TG_high": 479, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 10.6}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 9.3}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 8.3}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 7.6}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.0}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.0}]},
 {"TG_low": 480, "TG_high": 489, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 11.7}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 9.3}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 8.4}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 7.6}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.1}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.1}]},
 {"TG_low": 490, "TG_high": 499, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 11.6}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 9.6}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 8.4}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 7.6}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.2}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.2}]},
 {"TG_low": 500, "TG_high": 509, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 12.1}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 9.2}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 8.4}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 7.5}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.1}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.2}]},
 {"TG_low": 510, "TG_high": 519, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 12.3}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 9.9}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 8.5}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 7.9}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.1}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.3}]},
 {"TG_low": 520, "TG_high": 529, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 12.0}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 9.8}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 8.7}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 7.7}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.1}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.3}]},
 {"TG_low": 530, "TG_high": 539, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 12.0}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 9.8}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 8.7}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 7.8}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.2}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.3}]},
 {"TG_low": 540, "TG_high": 549, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 11.3}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 10.0}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 8.8}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 7.8}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.4}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.3}]},
 {"TG_low": 550, "TG_high": 559, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 12.2}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 10.2}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 8.8}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.0}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.4}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.2}]},
 {"TG_low": 560, "TG_high": 569, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 13.8}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 10.2}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 8.7}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.1}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.2}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.2}]},
 {"TG_low": 570, "TG_high": 579, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 15.4}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 10.4}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 8.9}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.0}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.3}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.2}]},
 {"TG_low": 580, "TG_high": 589, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 12.7}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 10.5}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.1}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.3}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.3}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.4}]},
 {"TG_low": 590, "TG_high": 599, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 12.5}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 10.5}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.2}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.3}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.2}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 5.9}]},
 {"TG_low": 600, "TG_high": 609, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 13.7}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 10.5}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 8.9}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.2}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.6}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.3}]},
 {"TG_low": 610, "TG_high": 619, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 15.4}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 10.5}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.1}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.4}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.5}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.4}]},
 {"TG_low": 620, "TG_high": 629, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 16.4}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 11.3}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.2}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.5}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.5}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.4}]},
 {"TG_low": 630, "TG_high": 639, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 14.1}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 11.6}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.4}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.2}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.3}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.2}]},
 {"TG_low": 640, "TG_high": 649, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 14.8}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 11.0}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.1}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.1}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.5}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.6}]},
 {"TG_low": 650, "TG_high": 659, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 14.2}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 11.0}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.2}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.3}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.5}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.4}]},
 {"TG_low": 660, "TG_high": 669, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 15.0}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 10.9}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.2}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.3}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.5}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.5}]},
 {"TG_low": 670, "TG_high": 679, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 14.2}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 11.0}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.3}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.6}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.6}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.7}]},
 {"TG_low": 680, "TG_high": 689, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 16.7}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 11.5}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.8}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.3}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.4}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.7}]},
 {"TG_low": 690, "TG_high": 699, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 15.0}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 11.6}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.8}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.4}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.8}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.5}]},
 {"TG_low": 700, "TG_high": 709, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 16.6}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 11.5}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.5}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.5}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.8}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.9}]},
 {"TG_low": 710, "TG_high": 719, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 14.5}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 10.9}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.7}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.5}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.8}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.4}]},
 {"TG_low": 720, "TG_high": 729, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 16.5}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 11.7}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.5}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.5}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.6}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.6}]},
 {"TG_low": 730, "TG_high": 739, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 18.2}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 12.2}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.9}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.9}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 8.2}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.6}]},
 {"TG_low": 740, "TG_high": 749, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 17.5}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 11.7}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.9}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.5}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.9}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.6}]},
 {"TG_low": 750, "TG_high": 759, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 17.5}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 12.9}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 10.2}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.8}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 8.1}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.4}]},
 {"TG_low": 760, "TG_high": 769, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 19.2}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 11.4}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 9.9}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.7}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 8.3}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.5}]},
 {"TG_low": 770, "TG_high": 779, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 17.3}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 13.4}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 10.4}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.6}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 8.2}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.7}]},
 {"TG_low": 780, "TG_high": 789, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 23.9}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 12.3}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 10.4}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 9.1}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 7.9}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.7}]},
 {"TG_low": 790, "TG_high": 799, "nonHDL-C": [{"low": 0, "high": 99, "factor": 15.6}, {"low": 100, "high": 129, "factor": 13.0}, {"low": 130, "high": 159, "factor": 10.7}, {"low": 160, "high": 189, "factor": 8.7}, {"low": 190, "high": 219, "factor": 8.0}, {"low": 220, "high": 100000, "factor": 6.7}]}]

